# Latin original for "Would you have a great empire?" saying, by Publilius Syrus

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, passage-request

Can someone provide the original Latin translation for Publilius Syrus's famous axiom, "Would you have a great empire? Rule over yourself." I have searched online and not been able to find it in Latin.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this site](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/syrus.html), it would be:

> *Imperium habere vis magnum? impera tibi*

The source is his collection of sayings, *Sententiae*. Their English version might have been partly popularised by the [translation](https://archive.org/details/moralsayingspub00lymagoog) done by Darius Lyman, in the mid XIX century.