# Would You Have a Great Empire--Revisited?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, homonyms

This is a follow-up to [this older question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10667/79). So "imperium habere vis magnum?" given as "Would you have a great Empire?". If this is indirect speech, then He (Publilius Syrus) said that the empire (imperium--accusative) has (habere--infinitive) great power (vis magnum).

So how is the doubt, in the questioning, "would-you-have...?", expressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latin has a large number of homonyms, and all the grammarians have a chapter on the subject: Donatus, Quintilian and Isidore all mention ***olla,*** an old form of *illa,* used by Cicero as a derogatory form for "that"

> ***olla*** that; ***olla*** a cooking pot.

or this

> ***eo*** there; ***eo*** I am going.

and even

> ***Vis*** you wish (+infinitive); from *volo, vis, vult, volumus, vultis, volunt.*
>   ***Vis*** (nominative) force strength.

*Vis habere,* means "you wish to have"

And here are another twenty to watch out for:

> ***Aggere;  canes;   (canam,canas,cani); decora; fide; labes; labor; latere; leges, -is; malam, -is; mane; mensis; miseris; nisi; nota; novi; rege, -es, -is, -i; rosa; sede, -es; vade, -es, is; velis; veneris, Veneris; vires; voces.***

Comment: read "vis" as power, but, then power would have been "vim"; it is now sorted.

Comment: And *oppĭdō* as the new question from Luchonacho reminds me.